# Удаление репозитория linux

Tags: linux, debian, kubuntu, deb

Пытаюсь удалить репозиторий из линукса, но он не удаляется.
(ключ, о котором написано ниже -- удалил)

sudo add-apt-repository --remove deb https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease

Ошб:8 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease
Следующие подписи не могут быть проверены, так как недоступен открытый ключ: NO_PUBKEY 1F3045A5DF7587C3

W: Произошла ошибка при проверке подписи. Репозиторий не обновлён, и будут использованы предыдущие индексные файлы. Ошибка GPG: https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease: Следующие подписи не могут быть проверены, так как недоступен открытый ключ: NO_PUBKEY 1F3045A5DF7587C3

W: Не удалось получить https://repo.skype.com/deb/dists/stable/InRelease  Следующие подписи не могут быть проверены, так как недоступен открытый ключ: NO_PUBKEY 1F3045A5DF7587C3

W: Некоторые индексные файлы скачать не удалось. Они были проигнорированы, или вместо них были использованы старые версии.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

найди его в файлах `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*` и удали. потом `apt-get update`

Comment: В обычном файле .list его нет, файл .list.d — пустой. Судя по ответу их может быть несколько… Поищу тогда, отпишусь

Comment: @AR1ESDX1Y, файл `.list.d` не может быть пустым, потому что это папка.

Comment: @eri и правда, папка. Когда через nano открываешь, открывается якобы пустой текстовый редактор, а надпись о том что это каталог -- не заметил. Спасибо тебе!